# How to access a sub-matrix of a multi-dimensional matrix in OpenCV function?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have a multi-dimensional matrix A of size 100x100x100 and I want to get a sub-matrix of A, for example `A[10:20, 20:30, 30:40]`. When the original matrix has two dimensions, OpenCV has a Mat operator to access the sub-matrix , for example: `A(Range(10,20), Range(20,30))`

For a multi-dimensional matrix, is there any efficient way to do this access? I am asking this because I need to copy the sub-matrix into another place.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the image is 100 rows x 100 cols x 100 planes x n channels, or whether it is 100 rows x 100 cols x 100 channels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Answer 1**

If mat A is 3D 100 rows x 100 cols x 100 planes x n channels, you can use [Mat Mat::operator()(const Range* ranges) const](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) like this::

```
std::vector<Range> ranges;
ranges.push_back(Range(10,20));
ranges.push_back(Range(20,30));
ranges.push_back(Range(30,40));

Mat B = A(&ranges[0]);
```

B will be 10x10x10 x n channels

---

**Answer 2**

If however mat A is 100 rows x 100 cols x 100 channels, that is just a 100 channel 2D mat. You can do this:

```
Mat B = A(Range(10,20), Range(20,30));  // B will be 10x10x100
```

Now you need to select channels 30:40 from B, you would need to use [void mixChannels(const Mat* src, size_t nsrcs, Mat* dst, size_t ndsts, const int* fromTo, size_t npairs)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels):

```
Mat C(10, 10, CV_MAKETYPE(A.depth(), 10));
int from_to[] = { 10,0, 11,1, 12,2, 13,3, 14,4,
                  15,5, 16,6, 17,7, 18,8, 19,9};
mixChannels(&B, 1, &C, 1, fromTo, 10);
```

C will then be 10 rows x 10 cols x 10 channels as required. This is a bit messy but I don't know a better way.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you have said. But it turns out that B is a 10*10*100 matrix. The channels are still 100 not 10. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I updated my answer, it sounds like you have a 2D image with a 100 channels. My original answer, only catered for a 3D image with 1 channel.